# How to create a new column in a df accumulating the values of another column with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, accumulate

I have a **df** with the following structure:

[image]

I would like to ***accumulate*** *in a new column* called "Flight1_Accumulated" **the sum of the past rows in Flight1**. As an example, for index 2020-03-01, this new column will contain the sum of 2020-01-01, 2020-02-01 and 2020-03-01.

I think that probably pandas has an specific function to solve it without iterate rows. Probably `dataframe.cumsum()` can do it.

The expected results (made with Excel) is:
[image]

**Does anyone know how to solve it?**

Comment: Can you add expected output? [Also is possible don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) ?

Comment: Expected results added

Comment: So you need `df['Flight1_Accumulated'] = df['Flight1'].cumsum()` ?